# Arduino Mega 2560 + BL-TB6560+ Stepper

Tags: stepper

I am working on an Arduino Mega 2560 and BL-TB6560-V2.0 driver for running a stepper motor. Initially I was able to run the stepper in both direction with code given and a schematic as per this image.

[image: schematic wiring].

```
int dirpin = 7;
int dirH = 12;
int steppin = 9;

void setup() {
  pinMode(dirpin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(steppin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dirH, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(dirpin, LOW); // Set the direction.
  digitalWrite(dirH, LOW);
  delay(1000);
  for (int i = 0; i<32767; i++) {
    // Iterate for 4000 microsteps.(32767)
    digitalWrite(steppin, LOW); // This LOW to HIGH change is what creates the
    digitalWrite(steppin, HIGH); // "Rising Edge" so the easydriver knows to when to step.
    delayMicroseconds(50);
  }
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(dirpin, LOW); // Set the direction.
  digitalWrite(dirH, HIGH);
  for (int j = 0; j<32767; j++) {
    // Iterate for 4000 microsteps.
    digitalWrite(steppin, LOW); // This LOW to HIGH change is what creates the
    digitalWrite(steppin, HIGH); // "Rising Edge" so the easydriver knows to when to step.
    delayMicroseconds(50);
  }
}
```

But now when I am trying it, the same stepper is not rotating. What could be the reason? I have checked the driver voltage, it's ok, and the code and schematic is the same.

[image: schematic Diagram]

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Schematic photo is not bad by itself. It's the bad drawing, the photo angle, the bad lighting and the poor contrast.

Comment: There is no ground connection to the arduino on the schematic, hope there is one in the real world.

Comment: Why do you inverse the polarity on the 24V site ? Is this a mistake in the drawing ?

Answer (score 1):

I just removed the ENE(+) pin of the driver, which was connected to the +5V. Now it's working and the stepper is rotating.

I just got a hint from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-s5-2p9dRoU).